# Tracking down cause of Spring's "not eligible for auto-proxying"

Tags: java, spring, aop

When you start messing around with Spring's auto-proxy stuff, you often run into this behaviour as documented:

> Classes that implement the
>   BeanPostProcessor  interface are
>   special, and so they are treated
>   differently by the container. All
>   BeanPostProcessors  and their directly
>   referenced beans will be instantiated
>   on startup, as part of the special
>   startup phase of the
>   ApplicationContext, then  all those
>   BeanPostProcessors will be registered
>   in a sorted fashion - and applied to
>   all further beans. Since AOP
>   auto-proxying is implemented as a
>   BeanPostProcessor  itself, no
>   BeanPostProcessors or directly
>   referenced beans are eligible for
>   auto-proxying (and thus will not have
>   aspects 'woven' into them.
>
> For any such bean, you should see an
>   info log message: “Bean 'foo' is not
>   eligible for getting processed by all
>   BeanPostProcessors (for example: not
>   eligible for auto-proxying)”.

In other words, if I write my own BeanPostProcessor, and that class directly references other beans in the context, then those referenced beans will not be eligible for auto-proxying, and a message is logged to that effect.

My problem is that tracking down where that direct reference is can be very difficult, since the "direct reference" can in fact be a chain of transitive dependencies that ends up taking in half the beans in the application context. All Spring gives you is that single info message, and it's not really much help, beyond telling you when a bean has been caught in this web of references.

The BeanPostProcessor I'm developing does have direct references to other beans, but it's a very limited set of references. Despite this, pretty much every bean in my context is then being excluded from being auto-proxied, according to the log messages, but I can't see where that dependency is happening.

Has anyone found a better way of tracking this down?

Comment: You can also get that information message for `PersistenceExceptionTranslator` classes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just to bring some closure to this question, the collapse of the uninitialized object graph was caused by the `BeanPostProcessor` using `@Autowired` to get its dependencies, and the autowire mechanism effectively caused every other bean definition to be initialized before my `BeanPostProcessor` got a chance to have a say in the matter. The solution is not to use autowiring for your BPPs.

Comment: This isn't a solution; what do I do instead when I need beans in my post processor?

Answer (score 52):

Follow this recipe:

1. Open `BeanPostProcessorChecker` in your IDE (it's an inner class of `AbstractApplicationContext`)
2. Set a breakpoint on `if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {` in the method `postProcessAfterInitialization`
3. Run your code
4. When you hit the breakpoint, look for calls to `getBean(String,Class<T>)` in your stack trace.

   One of these calls will try to create a `BeanPostProcessor`. That bean should be the culprit.

**Background**

Imagine this situation:

```
public class FooPP implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Autowire
    private Config config;
}
```

When Spring has to create `config` (since it's a dependency of `FooPP`), it has a problem: The contract says that all `BeanPostProcessor` must be applied to every bean that is being created. But when Spring needs `config`, there is at least one PP (namely `FooPP`) which isn't ready for service!

This gets worse when you use an `@Configuration` class to define this bean:

```
@Configuration
public class BadSpringConfig {
     @Lazy @Bean public Config config() { return new Config(); }
     @Lazy @Bean public FooPP fooPP() { return new FooPP(); }
}
```

Every configuration class is a bean. That means to build a bean factory from `BadSpringConfig`, Spring needs to apply the post-processor `fooPP` but in order to do that, it first needs the bean factory ...

In this example, it's possible to break one of the cyclic dependencies. You can make `FooPP` implement `BeanFactoryAware` to get Spring inject the `BeanFactory` into the post processor. That way, you don't need autowiring.

Later in the code, you can lazily ask for the bean:

```
private LazyInit<Config> helper = new LazyInit<Config>() {
    
    @Override
    protected InjectionHelper computeValue() {
        return beanFactory.getBean( Config.class );
    }
};

@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization( Object bean, String beanName ) throws BeansException {
     String value = helper.get().getConfig(...);
}
```

([source for LazyInit](http://blog.pdark.de/2010/03/04/java-tricks-lazy-initialization/))

To break the cycle between the bean factory and the post processor, you need to configure the post processor in an XML config file. Spring can read that and build all the structures without getting confused.

Comment: is this solution still suitable in multithreading application like web services ?

Comment: `LazyInit` is thead safe, so yes.

Comment: I was able to use this to track down this issue when I was converting a Jersey app to Spring Boot.  Turns out I had a bean called "conversionService", and ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor looks for an (optional) bean with that name.  Since it was a BeanPostProcessor referencing my bean, my beans referenced by my conversion service were not getting wired properly (their @Autowired fields weren't being set, for instance).

Comment: `BeanPostProcessorChecker` has since been moved to `PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate` class as of Spring Framework 4

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it's of any help, but the Eclipse [Spring IDE](http://springide.org)'s
[graph view](http://springide.org/project/wiki/BeansGraph) looks like it could be helpful in sorting out bean references..