# Spring @Async Not Working

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

An `@Async` method in a `@Service`-annotated class is not being called asynchronously - it's blocking the thread.

I've got `<task: annotation-driven />` in my config, and the call to the method is coming from outside of the class so the proxy should be being hit. When I step through the code, the proxy is indeed hit, but it doesn't seem to go anywhere near any classes related to running in a task executor.

I've put breakpoints in `AsyncExecutionInterceptor` and they never get hit. I've debugged into `AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` and can see advice getting applied.

The service is defined as an interface (with the method annotated `@Async` there for good measure) with the implementation's method annotated `@Async` too. Neither are marked `@Transactional`.

Any ideas what may have gone wrong?

-=UPDATE=-

Curiously, it works *only* when I have my `task` XML elements in my app-servlet.xml file, and not in my app-services.xml file, and if I do my component scanning over services from there too. Normally I have one XML file with only controllers in it (and restrict the component-scan accordingly), and another with services in it (again with a component-scan restricted such that it doesn't re-scan the controllers loaded in the other file).

**app-servlet.xml**

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config" 
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd"
>
<task:annotation-driven executor="executor" />
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="7"/>

<!-- Enable controller annotations -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.package.store">
    <!-- <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" /> -->
</context:component-scan>

<tx:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

**app-services.xml** (doesn't work when specified here)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Set up Spring to scan through various packages to find annotated classes -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.package.store">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <task:annotation-driven executor="han" />
    <task:executor id="han" pool-size="6"/>
    ...
```

Am I missing something glaringly obvious in my configuration, or is there some subtle interplay between config elements going on?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Spring' `@ASync` type, and not one from another library?

Comment: `import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;` is what I'm using. I've seen that when the proxy is getting invoked, it thinks the declared class (the interface) doesn't have any class or method-level annotations on it - which is a lie!

Comment: Just to double check, the method is getting called externally, not from within the service correct?  And you're calling the method on the service that was constructed from Spring, not a service you've "new"ed up?

Comment: @Pace Yep, definitely from another class. In fact, I've tried it from two different classes (a `@Controller` and another `@Service`). The service itself is annotated `@Service` and created from a package-scan. The proxy doesn't think there's any advice on the class, even though I can see advise getting added on context startup. Any ideas of other things I can check?

Comment: How are you running the code?  When I've called `@Async` methods in JUnit tests using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`, the thread seems to hang.  How is the `@Async` method being called?  In what context?  Spring MVC?

Comment: Did you configure an executor bean and set its id as the value of the "executor" attribute in the <task:annotation-driven> config? The docs seem to imply that an executor is needed for @Async: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-namespace

Comment: @sdouglass I didn't have an executor defined, but after having added one, it still doesn't work :( `<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" /><task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>`

Comment: Can you please provide the code for your service interface, service implementation, and the code that is calling the @Async method?

Comment: Works for me with config in my service xml file and not servlet/mvc xml file. Seemed like it wasn't working at first. Using breakpoint debugger, my IDE would break in the @Async method but my Web browser was still waiting for a response to its request. I put `System.err.println("thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());` in service and @Async, saw different thread names. Lastly I put a sleep(10000) in the @Async method before the thread name logging, turned off the breakpoints, and that time the browser got a response right away and I saw the @Async thread name logged 10 seconds later.

Comment: @sdouglass Can you provide a copy of your services XML file? I'm wondering if there's something in mine conflicting with the task-annotation-driven declaration.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into the exact same issue: defining the task elements (and component scanning for the components) in my servlet.xml works as expected, but it doesn't work in the applicationContext.xml.  Unfortunately this just kills the modularity.

Comment: @ach Sadly not, and I don't work at the same company where I experienced this problem any more. Something worth looking into is the hierarchy and relationship between the root application context and the web application context. Spring MVC apps have both, but I'm not certain what the relationship between them is. Good luck!

Comment: @sdouglass an explicit executor isn't required - Spring will use defaults if you don't specify an executor. See http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/05/task-scheduling-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

With the help of this [excellent answer by Ryan Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7774597/1311394), I was able to figure this out (at least for my specific problem).

In short, the context loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` (generally from applicationContext.xml) is the parent of the context loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` (generally from `*-servlet.xml`).  If you have the bean with the `@Async` method declared/component-scanned in both contexts, the version from the child context (`DispatcherServlet`) will override the one in the parent context (`ContextLoaderListener`).  I verified this by excluding that component from component scanning in the `*-servlet.xml` -- it now works as expected.

Comment: Sadly I can't verify this fix as I don't have access to the code any more, but I'm almost certain this is the problem. The relationship between the root and web contexts had been niggling me for a while. Many thanks to you and Ryan Stewart!

Comment: I've been running into the same problem, and this was exactly the solution - thanks for posting, ach.

Comment: please  tell me what is solution. I also have same problem. What can i do to solve this issue?

Comment: The solution should be apparent if you've actually read and understand this answer.  If this is the same issue, you're component scanning the bean with the `@Async` twice, once in each context.  So stop doing that.

Answer (score 48):

For me the solution was to add `@EnableAsync` on my `@Configuration` annotated class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("bla.package")
@EnableAsync
public class BlaConfiguration {

}
```

Now the class in package `bla.package` which has `@Async` annotated methods can really have them called asynchronously.

Comment: this also was the case for me!! tanx

Answer (score 18):

Jiří Vypědřík's answer solved my problem. Specifically,

> 2. Check if your method annotated with @Async is public.

Another useful information from Spring tutorials https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/:

> Creating a local instance of the FacebookLookupService class does NOT 
>   allow the findPage method to run asynchronously. It must be created inside 
>   a @Configuration class or picked up by @ComponentScan.

What this means is that if you had a static method Foo.bar(), calling it in that manner wouldn't execute it in async, even if it was annotated with @Async. You'll have to annotate Foo with @Component, and in the calling class get an @Autowired instance of Foo.

Ie, if you have a annotated method bar in class Foo:

```
@Component
class Foo { 
   @Async
   public static void bar(){ /* ... */ }

   @Async
   public void bar2(){ /* ... */ }
}
```

An in your caller class:

```
class Test {

  @Autowired Foo foo;

  public test(){
     Foo.bar(); // Not async
     foo.bar(); // Not async
     foo.bar2(); // Async
  }

}
```

Edit: Seems like calling it statically also doesn't execute it in async.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Singlehandedly explained all the issues I had, thank you!

Comment: thanks, it was the magic of "and in the calling class get an @Autowired instance of Foo" which did the trick!

Answer (score 11):

1. Try adding `proxy-target-class="true"` to all `<*:annotation-driven/>` elements that support this attribute.
2. Check if your method annotated with `@Async` is public.

Answer (score 9):

In my case the `@Async` method was defined in same class as the sync method that used it, and that apparently caused all jobs to hang on current thread.

Bad

```java
@Component
@EnableAsync
public class TranslationGapiReader {
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<GapiFile> readFile(String fileId) {
        try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (Exception exc) { throw new RuntimeException("ololo", exc); }
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }

    public Stream<GapiFile> readFiles(Iterable<String> fileIds) {
        List<CompletableFuture<GapiFile>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String fileId: fileIds) {
            futures.add(readFile(fileId));
        }
        return Stream.empty();
    }
}
```

Good

```java
@Component
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncGapiFileReader {
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<TranslationGapiReader.GapiFile> readFile(String fileId) {
        try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (Exception exc) { throw new RuntimeException("ololo", exc); }
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@EnableAsync
public class TranslationGapiReader {
    @Autowired
    AsyncGapiFileReader asyncGapiFileReader;

    public Stream<GapiFile> readFiles(Iterable<String> fileIds) {
        List<CompletableFuture<GapiFile>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String fileId: fileIds) {
            futures.add(asyncGapiFileReader.readFile(fileId));
        }
        return Stream.empty();
    }
}
```

I'm not Spring guru enough to understand why does it only work when the `@Async` method is in a different class, but that's what fixes the issue from my observations.

Comment: the reason it doesn't work in Bad example is that because one method calls another within the same class, so Spring is not able to make an async autogenerate proxy in-between. The same would apply to any spring annotation, like Retryable or Transaction

Comment: If someone is interested in more details - check Dynamic Proxy and CgLib approaches

Comment: Is `@EnableAsync` required in both services? (aka the one with the `@Async` method and the one that calls it)

Comment: @Zap I wish I remembered, guess the most reliable way is through trial and error. If someone finds out, would be great if they could update the answer. I would bet on it not being needed on `TranslationGapiReader`

Comment: I was in a similar situation and I didn't need the annotation on either service layer - only on the `MainApplication` class.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly make your `.xml` config looks like:

```
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10" />
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="10" />
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler" proxy-target-class="true" />
```

(Yes, scheduler count and executor thread pool size is configurable)

Or just use default:

```
<!-- enable task annotation to support @Async, @Scheduled, ... -->
<task:annotation-driven />
```

Secondly make sure `@Async` methods are public.

Answer (score 2):

@Async can not be used in conjunction with lifecycle callbacks such as @PostConstruct. To asynchonously initialize Spring beans you currently have to use a separate initializing Spring bean that invokes the @Async annotated method on the target then.

```
public class SampleBeanImpl implements SampleBean {

  @Async
  void doSomething() { … }
}


public class SampleBeanInititalizer {

  private final SampleBean bean;

  public SampleBeanInitializer(SampleBean bean) {
    this.bean = bean;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void initialize() {
    bean.doSomething();
  }
}
```

[source](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async)

Comment: When you say "currently", what version of Spring are you referring to?

Comment: this is citation from Spring 3.0.x documentation, but i'm facing the same on Spring 4.3.6 and was able to make it work this way

Answer (score 2):

You need 3 lines of code for Async to work

1. in applicationContext.xml
2. At class level @EnableAsync
3. @Async at method level

@Service
@EnableAsync
public myClass {

@Async
public void myMethod(){

}

Answer (score 1):

I realized following the tutorial [async-method tutorial code](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-async-method) that my issue source was: the bean with the annotated `@Async` method was not being created wrapped in a proxy.
I started digging and realized that there was a message saying

> Bean 'NameOfTheBean' is not eligible for getting processed by all
>   BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201726/tracking-down-cause-of-springs-not-eligible-for-auto-proxying) responses about this issue and its basically that BeanPostProcessors are required by every Bean, so every bean injected here and its dependencies will be excluded to be processed later by other BeanPostProcessors, because it corrupted the life cycle of beans. So identify which is the `BeanPostProcessor` that is causing this and dont use or create beans inside of it.

In my case i had this configuration

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    private DefaultPayloadLoggingInterceptor payloadLoggingInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        interceptors.add(securityInterceptor);
        interceptors.add(payloadLoggingInterceptor);
    }
}
```

`WsConfigurerAdapter` is actually a `BeanPostProcessor` and you realize it because there is always a pattern: `@Configuration` that extends classes and override some of it functions to install or tweak beans involved in some non functional features, like web service or security.

In the aforementioned example you have to override the `addInterceptors` and added interceptors beans, so if you are using some annotation like `@Async` inside `DefaultPayloadLoggingInterceptor` it wont work. What is the solution? Get ride of `WsConfigurerAdapter` to start. 
After digging a bit i realized a class named `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping` at the end was which had all valid interceptors, so i did it manually insted of overriding a function.

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    private DefaultPayloadLoggingInterceptor payloadLoggingInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    public void setupInterceptors(PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping endpointMapping) {
        EndpointInterceptor[] interceptors = {
                securityInterceptor,
                payloadLoggingInterceptor
        };

        endpointMapping.setInterceptors(interceptors);
    }
}
```

So this will be run after all `BeanPostProcessor` have done their job. The `setupInterceptors` function will run when that party is over and install the interceptors beans. This use case may be extrapolated to cases like Security.

Conclusions:

- If you are using a @Configuration extending from some class that runs some given functions automatically and you override them, you are probably inside of a `BeanPostProcessor`, so dont inject beans there and try to use AOP behaviour, because it wont work, and you will see Spring tells it to you with the beforementioned message in the console. In those cases dont use beans but objects (using the `new` clause).
- If you need to use beans digg about which class is carrying the beans you want to setup at the end, `@Autowired` it and add those beans like i did before.

I hope this may save some time for you.

Answer (score 0):

write a independent Spring configuration for asynchronous bean.
for example:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig {

    /**
     *  used by  asynchronous event listener.
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name = "asynchronousListenerExecutor")
    public Executor createAsynchronousListenerExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

I overcome this problem with this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:
1. In config create bean for `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`

```
@Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    }
```

2. In service method where @Async is used add

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public void asyncMethod(){
    //do something
    }
```

This should get @Async working.