# @Async does not work with task:executor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I'm trying to call a method in Spring-powered bean asynchronously using `@Async`. I defined an executor in XML:

```
<task:executor id="emailTasksExecutor" pool-size="1" />
```

and here is my method:

```
@Override
@Async("emailTasksExecutor")
public void sendEmail()
{
    ...
}
```

And the method does not get called at all when I use qualifier (`emailTasksExecutor`). However, if I remove it, everything works ok. But in this case the [default executor is used](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async) and I need to change this behaviour.

I thought the problem is that my class does not implement any interfaces, and something went wrong with proxies. But extracting the interface did not help.

Comment: What does `task:annotation-driven` look like?

Comment: Also, will the method work is you increase the pool size?

Comment: @geoand `<task:annotation-driven />` - nothing special. I'll try to increase pool size.

Comment: Hmm, no, it does not work. Also, replacing `<task:executor>` with `<bean id="emailTasksExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">` does not work too.

Comment: which version of the Spring framework are you using?

Comment: Spring version is 3.2.8.RELEASE

Comment: This answer *may* help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610563/spring-async-not-working

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10276 I think this is it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the problem was my `maven-aspectj-plugin`. I found the solution [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10276). All I need to do is to add `mode="aspectj"` to the `task:annotation-driven`.