# PreAuthorize doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm writing a socket server (no web-application !) application and want to use method-based security to handle my ACL needs. i followed a small tutorial i found [spring security by example](http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/03/spring-security-by-example-securing.html)

so far i configured:

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
</security:global-method-security>
<bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator">
        <bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="myPermissionEvaluator" />
    </property>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager id="authenticationmanager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationprovider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
<bean id="authenticationprovider" class="myAuthenticationProvider" />
```

With a service bean:

```
@Named
public class ChannelService {
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#channel, 'CHANNEL_WRITE')")
    public void writeMessage(Channel channel, String message) { ... }
}
```

Everything compiles and the application starts and works fine, but without access control. My debug log shows that my Evaluator is never called.

When i tried something similar with a `@Secured` annotation the annotation was evaluated and access was denied. but simple role based security isn't enough for my requirements.

**EDIT**
did some more tests: when i configure only secured-annotations="enabled" the role based security works. when configure pre-post-annotations="enabled" in ADDITION neither secured nor preauthorize works. when i configure only pre-post-annotations it still doesn't work.

**EDIT2**

some more tests:
with only secured_annotations="enabled" the call to my channelservice goes through the Cglib2AopProxy
as soon as i activate pre-post-annotations the call lands directly in the channelservice. no interceptor, no proxy, nothing.

I'm getting kind of desperate...

**EDIT3**

I debug-logged my testruns here is the part for spring-security

with only secured-annotations="enabled"

```
2012-04-12 13:36:46,171 INFO  [main] o.s.s.c.SpringSecurityCoreVersion - You are running with Spring Security Core 3.1.0.RELEASE
2012-04-12 13:36:46,174 INFO  [main] o.s.s.c.SecurityNamespaceHandler - Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.1.0.RELEASE
2012-04-12 13:36:49,042 DEBUG [main] o.s.s.a.m.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource - Caching method [CacheKey[mystuff.UserService; public void mystuff.UserService.serverBan(java.lang.String,mystuff.models.User,org.joda.time.DateTime)]] with attributes [user]
2012-04-12 13:36:49,138 DEBUG [main] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor - Validated configuration attributes
2012-04-12 13:36:49,221 DEBUG [main] o.s.s.a.m.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource - Caching method [CacheKey[mystuff.ChannelService; public void mystuff.ChannelService.writeMessage(mystuff.models.Channel,java.lang.String)]] with attributes [blubb]
2012-04-12 13:36:51,159 DEBUG [main] o.s.s.a.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using mystuff.GlobalchatAuthenticationProvider
2012-04-12 13:36:56,166 DEBUG [Timer-1] o.s.s.a.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using mystuff.GlobalchatAuthenticationProvider
2012-04-12 13:36:56,183 DEBUG [Timer-1] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public void mystuff.ChannelService.writeMessage(mystuff.models.Channel,java.lang.String); target is of class [mystuff.ChannelService]; Attributes: [blubb]
2012-04-12 13:36:56,184 DEBUG [Timer-1] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@312e8aef: Principal: mystuff.UserId@ced1752b; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Not granted any authorities
Exception in thread "Timer-1" org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AbstractAccessDecisionManager.checkAllowIfAllAbstainDecisions(AbstractAccessDecisionManager.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:88)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at mystuff.ChannelService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$3ad5e57f.writeMessage(<generated>)
    at mystuff.run(DataGenerator.java:109)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
2012-04-12 13:36:56,185 DEBUG [Timer-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@1cfe174, returned: 0
2012-04-12 13:36:56,185 DEBUG [Timer-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@da89a7, returned: 0
```

with pre-post-annotations="enabled"

```
2012-04-12 13:39:54,926 INFO  [main] o.s.s.c.SpringSecurityCoreVersion - You are running with Spring Security Core 3.1.0.RELEASE
2012-04-12 13:39:54,929 INFO  [main] o.s.s.c.SecurityNamespaceHandler - Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.1.0.RELEASE
2012-04-12 13:39:54,989 INFO  [main] o.s.s.c.m.GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser - Using bean 'expressionHandler' as method ExpressionHandler implementation
2012-04-12 13:39:59,812 DEBUG [main] o.s.s.a.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt mystuff.GlobalchatAuthenticationProvider
2012-04-12 13:39:59,850 DEBUG [main] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor - Validated configuration attributes
```

As far as i understand this log output spring doesn't realize my beans need to be proxied, so they aren't and so i don't get security.

**EDIT4**

I debug-logged the complete sprint startup... (thats one big log) and there i find:

```
2012-04-12 14:40:41,385 INFO [main] o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Bean 'channelService' of type [class mystuff.ChannelService] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

is there a way to figure out why? because as far as i understand it. because of @preauthorize the bean should be eligible. with only secured-annotations="enabled" i get a post processing log.

Comment: What version of Spring and Spring Security are You using?

Comment: @Roadrunner spring 3.1.0.RELEASE on everything.

Comment: Can you debug if "PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource#getAttributes()" gets called for your method when Spring initializes ?

Comment: @Luciano i can and it doesn't. it seems that because my PermissionEvaluator needs the channel service this service is created before the datasource (creation of the service is between loglines 215 (start) -702 (end); datasource is first mentioned in line 870 with "is not eligible for getting ....)

Comment: when i removed @inject ChannelService from my PermissionEvaluator the proxy was created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This configuration worked just as expected for me:

```
<bean id="securityExpressionHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" /> 

<bean id="preInvocationAdvice"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice"
    p:expressionHandler-ref="securityExpressionHandler" />

<util:list id="decisionVoters">
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter"
        c:pre-ref="preInvocationAdvice" />
</util:list>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
    c:decisionVoters-ref="decisionVoters" />

<sec:global-method-security
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

I got the log message:

```
WARN  org.springframework.security.access.expression.DenyAllPermissionEvaluator - 
    Denying user jack permission 'CHANNEL_WRITE' on object Channel[ name=null ]
```

And an exception:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

From a simple test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:META-INF/spring/application-context.xml")
public class SpringSecurityPrePostTest {

    @Autowired
    ChannelService channelService;

    @Test
    public void shouldSecureService() throws Exception {
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("jack", "sparrow");
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);

        channelService.writeMessage(new Channel(), "test");
    }
}
```

One thing I did diffrent was to use interface on a service and JDK proxies instead of cglib:

```
public interface ChannelService {

    void writeMessage(Channel channel, String message);
}
```

and:

```
@Component
public class ChannelServiceImpl implements ChannelService {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChannelServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and hasPermission(#channel, 'CHANNEL_WRITE')")
    public void writeMessage(Channel channel, String message) {
        LOG.info("Writing message {} to: {}" , message, channel);
    }

}
```

---

**UPDATE1:**

---

With this simplified config I get the same result:

```
<bean id="securityExpressionHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" /> 

<sec:global-method-security
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="securityExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>
```

---

**UPDATE2:**

---

The debug message from Edit4 indicates that `channelService` may not have bean proxied at all as it got classified as [`not eligible for auto-proxying`](http://www.google.pl/#q=not+eligible+for+auto-proxying). [This qiestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201726/tracking-down-cause-of-springs-not-eligible-for-auto-proxying) answers similar problem - try not to use `@Autowired` or any other mechanism based on `BeanPostProcessors` to set up the beans involved in security checks (i.e. `myPermissionEvaluator`).

---

**UPDATE3:**

---

You **cannot** use secured resources (i.e. services) within beans responsible for security checks! This creates a dependency loop and is a error in Your configuration. You **must** use lover level access (i.e. DAO) to check permissions, anything that is **not secured**! Implementing security checks using secured resources is **not what You want to do**.

If despite using not secured resources with `@Autowired` things don't work as expected, try using old-school XML confiuration style for all beans involved in security checks. Also remember that `<context:component-scan />` is in fact a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` and introduces the scanned beans into the `BeanFactory` after all the ones declared in XML are already there.

Comment: in my PermissionEvaluator is use the Channel and User service because user permissions on these objects are store in these objects. But ´@inject´ of these beans causes these two services to be created before the PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource. when i remove them, my evaluator is called properly. now i just have to figure out how to inject my proxied services into the evaluator without causing this.

Comment: @Laures see my extended answer for more tips.

Comment: the methods i use to check permissions are not secured (and wont be) but they are part of the service that has secured methods. i solved the problem by looking up the service object from the application context when i first need it. maybe not the cleanest solution but in my case there is no lower access level.

Comment: @Laures You should divide this service into 2 separete classes - one containing only not secured methods for use in security checks, and the other containing the secured methods for business use cases. Then both `@Inject` of unsecured service to Your `permissionEvaluator` and auto-proxying of secured one will work correctly. Even when not using secured methods, You're still using a class that You expect to be proxied with security checks - it's a dependency loop that should be removed by proposed division.

Comment: The third update saved my life. You CANNOT call services in your customPermissionEvaluator that have any kind of Pre/PostAuthorization. This just fails silently and authorization is never executed. I solved it by adding @Lazy to the aforementioned services when passed through my PermissionEvaluator constructor

Answer (score -1):

it works,
make sure  that you have `<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>` in your spring servlet (ie where you may have your `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`)

"sec" is from  `xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"`

Comment: as you can see i already have the global-method-security tag configured and this is no web application, so no servlet or anything.

Comment: @Laures what is the Named annotation that you are using? it's not a spring annotation, maybe you should try with Component anntotation

Comment: named is a jsr330 annotation that basictly means the same this as component, but its standartized and not spring specific. jsr 330 is implemented by spring.