# Alternatives to spring-security in Java (spring)

Tags: java, spring, authentication, authorization

I'm looking for a good security framework that allows to annotate parameter based access rules to methods.

Basicly i want to check if the authenticated user is allowed to call a certain method with a specific object as a parameter.

Spring security would serve my needs but because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110374/preauthorize-doesnt-work) ([spring forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?125300-PreAuthenticate-not-having-any-effekt)) i'm looking for alternatives if i'm unable to get it to work.

Requirements:

- method security based on config or annotations, i want to avoid puting my security code insite my service methods
- rules are based on parameters of the methods, simple role based security is not enough
- spring support out of the box is a plus

Any recommendations?

Comment: If your existing application on Spring framework, then use the spring itself which makes sense.

Comment: what is the EJB way? @Phani as i wrote: spring security doesn't work in my application and it might be it never will. so i'm preparing for the worst and look for ALTERNATIVES

Comment: Then only approach is left for you is to use JAAS
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jaas/index.html

Comment: It makes me cringe to say it, but can you roll your own security check using a method interceptor and apply it accross your beans using AOP?

Comment: @CraigSwing i feel with you there, but so far thats probably what i will do if everything fails with spring security.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apache Shiro stands in competition to Spring Security. Is easier, covers more.
See [here](http://shiro.apache.org/spring.html).

Comment: Two facts stated here, one correct, one wrong.[br]It looks a LOT easier and seems easier is true. Covers a lot more is probably wrong. It does not have Oauth OR OpenID yet. Can you say yahoo, facebook, amazon, Microsoft-Whatever, Twitter, Baidu, and up to 50 more of the top Identiy providers in the world . . . unavailable to be used??

Comment: @Dennis, Shiro can be used in a non-JEE, non web application to communicate with the web. What I find "more" and a refreshingly logical architectural approach. I was convinced that an OAuth plugin existed, but it might well be still alpha? Missing OpenId support is indeed a pitty.