# JSF Friendly Security - Alternatives to Spring

Tags: security, jsf, authentication, spring-security, ldap

I have a working JSF Web Application and I need to add Authentication to.  I've had some difficulty getting Spring Security working because its seems like its pretty `.jsp` focused.

Is there something that works easily with JSF?

From this post: [Alternatives to spring-security in Java (spring)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10124859/2069812) (from 2012) I see that the main alternative is **Apache Shiro**

I was wondering if anything else has come along in the last 3 years and what the best library/process would be to work with an existing `.jsf` application.

I'll likely be doing LDAP authentication

Comment: [PicketLink](http://picketlink.org)  with [a jsf example](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-picketlink-quickstarts/tree/master/picketlink-authentication-idm-jsf)

Comment: I assume it can also work with tomcat?

Comment: Yes, I think it could, but if you have all advantages then I'm not sure. It is certainly more mature than shiro and independent of spring