# Spring is ignoring @Transactional annotations in Apache Shiro Realm class

Tags: spring, hibernate, shiro

I am using Spring for IOC and transaction management, and am planning to use Apache Shiro as the security library.

Whenever I want to check a user's permissions, I call `subject.isPermitted("right")`, whereupon Shiro checks for the permission using a datastore. Within these calls, a database connection is established, and I have annotated the method with `@Transactional`. However, I always receive an error that there is no Hibernate session bound to the thread whenever I execute the permission check.

The method is in the Realm class. I defined a custom Shiro Realm class:

```
@Component
public class MainRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

@Autowired
protected SysUserDao userDao;

@Transactional
protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    ...
    final SysUser user = this.userDao.findByUsername(un);
    ...
    return authInfo;
}

@Transactional
protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
    ...
    permissions = this.userDao.getAccessRights(un);
    ...
    return authInfo;
}
}
```

Apache Shiro uses a Servlet Filter, so I have the following defined in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

I am using programmatic configuration for Spring. Here is my App Config class:

```
@Configuration //Replaces Spring XML configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mycompany")
@EnableTransactionManagement //Enables declarative Transaction annotations
public class SpringAppConfig {

@Bean
public DataSource sqlServerDataSource() throws Exception {...}
@Bean
@Autowired
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {...}
@Bean
public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() throws Exception {...}
@Bean
public static PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {...}

@Bean
@Autowired
public DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager(MainRealm mainRealm) {
    final HashedCredentialsMatcher hcm = new HashedCredentialsMatcher(shiroHash);
    hcm.setHashIterations(shiroIter);
    hcm.setStoredCredentialsHexEncoded(shiroHexEncoded);
    mainRealm.setCredentialsMatcher(hcm);
    final DefaultWebSecurityManager sm = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
    sm.setRealm(mainRealm);
    return sm;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter(DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager) {
    final ShiroFilterFactoryBean filter = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
    filter.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
    return filter;
}

/**
 * This method needs to be static due to issues defined here:<br>
 * https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-222
 */
@Bean
public static LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
    LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lbpp = new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
    return lbpp;
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
public static DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
    return new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor(DefaultWebSecurityManager secMan) {
    AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor advBean = new AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor();
    advBean.setSecurityManager(secMan);
    return advBean;
}
}
```

To summarize the issue, I believe my MainRealm class is being wired properly (it has an @Autowired dependency to a DAO object and I verified that it is not null) with the exception of the @Transactional annotation. Due to this, I cannot directly call `user.isPermitted("")` as it prompts an error: `No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here`.

Would like to ask for help in checking whether I missed anything in my Spring configuration.

In the meantime I have hacked over this issue by calling the `user.isPermitted("")` function within a method in my Service class that's correctly bound by a @Transactional.

**EDIT** When I checked the logs for Spring initialization I can see this:

```
Bean 'mainRealm' of type [class com.x.security.MainRealm] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12359607/751634) it means `MainRealm` isn't being postprocessed by the transaction manager therefore any @Transactional annotations get ignored. If so, how can I correct this?

**EDIT 2** According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1385181/751634): "In other words, if I write my own BeanPostProcessor, and that class directly references other beans in the context, then those referenced beans will not be eligible for auto-proxying, and a message is logged to that effect." I just checked `ShiroFilterFactoryBean` and it is in fact a BeanPostProcessor. And the problem is it requires a `SecurityManager` instance that in turn requires a `MainRealm` instance. So both beans are autowired and are thus ineligible for proxying. I feel like I'm closer to the solution but I still can't resolve it.

Comment: You can try to move all transactional logic to some `UserService` with `@Transactional` or `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` annotations and use this service within your `MainRealm`.

Comment: I tried to autowire a Service class into my Realm, however, upon doing so, the Service class also encountered the `No hibernate session bound to thread` error, and its @Transactional annotations didn't seem to work anymore. It seems like I'm doing something wrong in initializing the Shiro objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The root cause of the issue is in fact due to the following:

**All BeanPostProcessors and their directly referenced beans will be instantiated on startup... Since AOP auto-proxying is implemented as a BeanPostProcessor itself, no BeanPostProcessors or directly referenced beans are eligible for auto-proxying (and thus will not have aspects 'woven' into them.**

Referenced SO question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201726/tracking-down-cause-of-springs-not-eligible-for-auto-proxying).

I have resolved this issue by decoupling the Realm bean creation from the SecurityManager bean creation.

The relevant change is from the following code:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager(MainRealm mainRealm) {
    final HashedCredentialsMatcher hcm = new HashedCredentialsMatcher(shiroHash);
    hcm.setHashIterations(shiroIter);
    hcm.setStoredCredentialsHexEncoded(shiroHexEncoded);
    mainRealm.setCredentialsMatcher(hcm);
    final DefaultWebSecurityManager sm = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
    sm.setRealm(mainRealm);
    return sm;
}
```

to the following code:

```
@Bean
public DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager() {
    final DefaultWebSecurityManager sm = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
    //sm.setRealm(mainRealm); -> set this AFTER Spring initialization so no dependencies
    return sm;
}
```

Then I use a ServletContextListener which listens to when the Spring context initialization completes and I have the both the `MainRealm` and `SecurityManager` beans. Then I just plug one bean inside another.

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    try {

        //Initialize realms
        final MainRealm mainRealm = (MainRealm)ctx.getBean("mainRealm");
        final DefaultWebSecurityManager sm = (DefaultWebSecurityManager)ctx.getBean("securityManager");
        sm.setRealm(mainRealm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error loading: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new Error("Critical system error", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`@Transactional` annotation can be used before :

- An interface def
- An interface method
- A class def
- A **PUBLIC** method of a class

As explained in the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-declarative-annotations)

The fact that your method is `protected` must be the reason of your problem, and your service method was maybe declared as `public` which would explained why it worked in that case

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I tried this and it didn't work. I think this may be an issue related to my misconfiguring Shiro objects with Spring.