# Adding @Transactional to a Bean that's referenced by a BeanPostProcessor

Tags: spring

Currently I have a Spring configuration set up this way:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public Manager manager(DataRetriever dataRetriever) { 
    Manager m = new Manager();
    m.setRetriever(dataRetriever); //DataRetriever is a @Component bean
    return m;
}

@Bean
public VendorFactoryBean factory() { 
    final VendorFactoryBean fb = new VendorFactoryBean(); 
    fb.setManager(manager());
    return fb;
}
```

`VendorFactoryBean` *requires* a `Manager` instance. `Manager` bean > `DataRetriever` bean.

Within `DataRetriever` I have a `@Transactional` annotation like so:

```
@Component("dataRetriever")
public class DataRetriever { 
    @Transactional public void retrieveStuff() {...} 
}
```

Now, `VendorFactoryBean` implements `BeanPostProcessor`. Here's where I run into problems.

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201726/tracking-down-cause-of-springs-not-eligible-for-auto-proxying), all BeanPostProcessors and their directly referenced beans will be instantiated on startup, and in addition: **Since AOP auto-proxying is implemented as a BeanPostProcessor itself, no BeanPostProcessors or directly referenced beans are eligible for auto-proxying (and thus will not have aspects 'woven' into them.**

In fact, the @Transactional annotation is ignored and I get an error: "No Hibernate session bound to this thread."

I have tried to move the `fb.setManager(manager());` call from the VendorFactoryBean and set it using another BeanPostProcessor, however in this case I cannot do so, because VendorFactoryBean is from a library and it contains an assertion that on instantiation a Manager instance must have already been set.

Would like to ask if there are possible solutions to this situation.

Edit: specific example [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922559/spring-is-ignoring-transactional-annotations-in-apache-shiro-realm-class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have thought of a solution for this specific situation.

Basically, **we decouple the DataRetriever bean from the Manager bean**.

(1) We revise the @Configuration class as follows:

```
@Bean
public Manager manager() { 
    Manager m = new Manager();
    //m.setRetriever(dataRetriever); !IMPT! remove this!
    return m;
}

@Bean
public VendorFactoryBean factory() { 
    final VendorFactoryBean fb = new VendorFactoryBean(); //implements BeanPostProcessor 
    fb.setManager(manager());
    return fb;
}
```

(2) We allow Spring to initialize the beans. First, the `VendorFactoryBean` bean is initialized together with the `Manager` bean. Then, the `DataRetriever` bean is initialized and its @Transactional annotations post-processed correctly.

(3) Since we're doing programmatic configuration, we have a `WebApplicationInitializer` class where we can plug in `ServletContextListeners`, like so:

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(SpringAppConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        // New listener to finalize initialization of Manager.
        container.addListener(new ManagerFinalizerListener(rootContext));
    }
}
```

(4) And finally we create a `ServletContextListener` class that ties the `DataRetriever` into the `Manager` bean.

```
public class ManagerFinalizerListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx;

    public ManagerFinalizerListener(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        final Manager mgr = (Manager)ctx.getBean("manager");
        mgr.setRetriever((DataRetriever)ctx.getBean("dataRetriever"));
    }
}
```

And this will be done after Spring context has completed initialization, therefore, no premature bean creation due to dependencies.