# not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-annotations

I getting following exception. Is there anyway  I get which bean not resolved or customized way handle the spring bean in sequence?
 org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'ThreadPoolTaskExecutor' of type [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: It isn't an exception it is a warning/information meesage. It already tells you which bean right there in the exception message. Generally you can ignore those messages.

Comment: Have you considered debugging it like [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19688634/1827854)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358783/class-not-eligible-for-getting-processed-by-all-beanpostprocessors)