# Main class doesn't finnish to start the application spring Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to start my spring app in eclipse but it seems that it's not finnishing to execute the starting process when I select RightBtn --> Run as --> Spring boot App. In fact eclipse is deploying my app and I'm able to interact with it via REST (http://localhost...). But when I see the console I see that it stops printing messages in the console just when it finishes to read the main method. (I put the logs in the result section)

I'm trying to figure out why thiis is happening because normally when I start a Spring application I've get something like what I'm posting in the output section:

I don't think it is related with the bean declaration, because I've see the following in the logs:

```
'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7738e7d1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

And as I saw in the following link ([Class not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358783/class-not-eligible-for-getting-processed-by-all-beanpostprocessors)) I should not be worried about it.  So no clue where the problem is.

I've tried many things, comment some of the labels I've included but still the same issue. I think I'm mixing too many labels so at some point my app can not continue and is not showing any errors.

I thought that I was wrong so I decided to download a code from git(https://github.com/igorkosandyak/spring-boot-kafka) in order to watch what the real output should look like.

```
package com.lexcorp.appianSer;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;


import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.lexcorp.trazas.*;//traerte la clase de trazas 

import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;


import com.lexcorp.config.AppPropert;
import com.lexcorp.config.ConfProp;
import com.lexcorp.config.ServerProperties;
import com.lexcorp.filters.*;
import com.lexcorp.productor.ProducerConsumerApplication;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;//ojo porque en el repo la clase de logger esta apuntada como com.springsource.org.apache.log4j 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;//tengo que decalara especificamente el bean invocado porque si no da error 
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;//importar p`ropiedad para evento 
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;//importar las propiedades para escuchar eventos 
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;//tratamos de hacer que la llamada al metodo sea asincrona al código
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;//importar eventos para ejecuccion tras el final del main



@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@ComponentScan("com.lexcorp.config")
@EnableScheduling
public class ControllerFPC {


    static Properties props;
    static String servletContext;
    static String propertiesName;
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ControllerFPC.class);

    @Autowired
    ServerProperties conf;

    @Autowired
    private ConfProp configurationData;

    @Value("${name}")
    private String name;/**/

    @Value("${app.topic.fpc}")
    private String topic;//esta es nueva para los valores mas complicados de recuperar que acumulan secciones y subsecciones

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;//@Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")//configuracion antigua de como se leia el servidor para el consumidor

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    private String groupid;/*invocamos el grupo donde vamos a incluir al grupo consumidor */

    //auto-offset-reset
    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset}")
    private String autooffsetr;/*invocamos el grupo donde vamos a incluir al auto-offset-reset consumidor para la politica de lectura de mensajes  */

    //key-deserializer
    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer}")
    private String keydeserial;/*invocamos el grupo donde vamos a incluir al deserializador de los mensajes consumidor */

    //value-deserializer
    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer}")
    private String valuedeserial;/*invocamos el grupo donde vamos a incluir al deserializador de los mensajes consumidor */


    @RequestMapping(value = "/available")
      public String available() {
        //startKafka();
        System.out.println("EStoy disponible");
        return "Spring in Action";// url http://localhost:8082/available

      }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/kafka")
      public String startKafka() {

        /*ProducerConsumerApplication pca= new ProducerConsumerApplication();
        pca.consumerStart();*/

        AppPropert prope= new AppPropert();
        props=prope.arranqueProp();
        ProducerConsumerApplication pca= new ProducerConsumerApplication();

        //pca.execute(topico,"Enviamos mensajes desde findById");//no funciona este emtodo 
        pca.readTop(props, "Procedemos a activar la lectura");

        return "Spring in Action";// url http://localhost:8082/available
      }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deletecell")
      public String postit() {// url http://localhost:8082/deletecell

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); //Use this instead 

        try {//iniciamos la configuracion en el momento inicial del evento 
            ControllerFPC con= new ControllerFPC();
            props=con.setProperties(props, conf);//rellenas el fichero de propiedades 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            logger.error("Exception : ControllerFPC.calculateLoadVal en la lectura del fichero de propiedades  " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8082/borrar");
            StringEntity params =new StringEntity("appians={\"id\":392,\"idlo\":LoadRegister} ");//new StringEntity("details={\"id\":\"aa\",\"idlo\":\"aaa\"} ");
            request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.setEntity(params);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            //handle response here...

        }catch (Exception ex) {

            //handle exception here

        }

        return "Spring in Action";// url http://localhost:8082/available
      }





    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/borrar")
    @ResponseBody
    public String findById(
      @RequestParam String appians, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {//@PathVariable long id
        ; 
        try {
            String topico=topic;
            ControllerFPC con= new ControllerFPC();
            props=con.setProperties(props, conf);//rellenas el fichero de propiedades 

            props=con.setPropiedades(props, bootstrapServers, topic);// incluyes groupid,  autooffsetr, keydeserial ,valuedeserial


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            logger.error("Exception : ControllerFPC.calculateLoadVal en la lectura del fichero de propiedades  " + e.getMessage());
        }

        String answer = appians.substring(appians.indexOf(":")+1,appians.indexOf(","));
        System.out.println(" has entrado en post recibir"+appians+ " extraccion --> "+answer);
        ServletFPC srv = new ServletFPC();
        String resultborrar=srv.borrarReg(answer,servletContext, propertiesName, logger, props);
        return "exito"+resultborrar;
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        servletContext=System.getProperty("catalina.home");
        propertiesName="config.properties";
        if(servletContext==null) {
            //la ruta antigua era en 
            //servletContext="aqui tenia la ruta absoluta";
        }
        servletContext=servletContext+"/instances/facturacioncorp001/webapps/";//La ruta linux es: "//instances//facturacioncorp001//webapps//properties//config.properties"
        ControllerFPC con= new ControllerFPC();
        props = new Properties();



        SpringApplication.run(ControllerFPC.class, args);



        logger.info("Starter of APP  " );


        System.out.println(" Finnish starting process ");

    }
    /*
    @Async @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)//ContextRefreshedEvent.class --> se lanza justo despuesd e que se creen todos los beans pero antes de que se inicie el servidor  , ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void doSomethingAfterStartup() {
        System.out.println("hello world, I have just started up");
    }*/
    /*@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000, initialDelay = 10)
    public void execDel() {
        System.out.println("Starting scheduled activity ");
        AppPropert prope= new AppPropert();
        props=prope.arranqueProp();
        ProducerConsumerApplication pca= new ProducerConsumerApplication();

        //pca.execute(topico,"Enviamos mensajes desde findById");//no funciona este emtodo 
        pca.readTop(props, "Procedemos a activar la lectura");
    }*/


    @Bean
    public PreFilter preFilter() {
        return new PreFilter();
    }
    @Bean
    public PostFilter postFilter() {
        return new PostFilter();
    }
    @Bean
    public ErrorFilter errorFilter() {
        return new ErrorFilter();
    }
    @Bean
    public RouteFilter routeFilter() {
        return new RouteFilter();
    }/**/

    @GetMapping("/datos")
    public ConfProp retrieveDatosFromConfigurations() {
        return configurationData;
    }

    public Properties setProperties(Properties props,ServerProperties conf) {

        try {
        props.setProperty("name", conf.getname());
        props.setProperty("environment", conf.getenvironment());
        props.setProperty("ORACLE_CHECK", conf.getORACLE_CHECK());
        props.setProperty("UPLOAD_SFTP", conf.getUPLOAD_SFTP());
        props.setProperty("SFTPUSER", conf.getSFTPUSER());
        props.setProperty("SFTPPASS", conf.getSFTPPASS());
        props.setProperty("TRAZA", conf.getTRAZA());
        props.setProperty("WSDL", conf.getWSDL());
        props.setProperty("REDIR", conf.getREDIR());
        props.setProperty("FSDIR", conf.getFSDIR());
        props.setProperty("DOWN_DIR", conf.getDOWN_DIR());
        props.setProperty("SOAPACTION", conf.getSOAPACTION());


        logger.info("Se ha completado la lectura del fichero de configuracion del config-server ControllerFPC.setProperties" );
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            //myLog.escribir(m1.toString()+"Exception: Error en metodo ServletFPC.crearConsulta no se ha enviado la request correctamente "+e.getMessage());
            logger.error("Exception: ControllerFPC.setProperties ha fallado la lectura del ficehro de configruacion colgado en el config server  " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return props;
    }
    public Properties setPropiedades(Properties props,String bootstrapServers, String topic) {
        try {

            props.setProperty("bootstrap-servers", bootstrapServers);
            props.setProperty("topic", topic);


            logger.info("Se ha completado la lectura del fichero de configuracion del config-server ControllerFPC.setProperties" );
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                //myLog.escribir(m1.toString()+"Exception: Error en metodo ServletFPC.crearConsulta no se ha enviado la request correctamente "+e.getMessage());
                logger.error("Exception: ControllerFPC.setPropiedades ha fallado la lectura del fichero de configruacion colgado en el config server  " + e.getMessage());
            }


        return props;
    }
    public Properties arranquePropiedad(String bootstrapServersP, String topicP) {
        Properties props= new Properties();
        bootstrapServersP=bootstrapServers;
        topicP=topic;
        try {

            props.setProperty("bootstrap-servers", bootstrapServers);
            props.setProperty("topic", topic);


            logger.info("Se ha completado la lectura del fichero de configuracion del config-server ControllerFPC.setProperties" );
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                //myLog.escribir(m1.toString()+"Exception: Error en metodo ServletFPC.crearConsulta no se ha enviado la request correctamente "+e.getMessage());
                logger.error("Exception: ControllerFPC.setPropiedades ha fallado la lectura del fichero de configruacion colgado en el config server  " + e.getMessage());
            }


        return props;
    }

    public String callfindById(
               String appians, Properties porpA) {//@PathVariable long id
                ; 
                String resultborrar="callfindById";
                try {
                    String topico=topic;
                    ControllerFPC con= new ControllerFPC();

                    String answer = appians.substring(appians.indexOf(":")+1,appians.indexOf(","));
                    System.out.println(" has entrado en post recibir"+appians+ " extraccion --> "+answer);
                    ServletFPC srv = new ServletFPC();
                    resultborrar=srv.borrarReg(answer,servletContext, propertiesName, logger, porpA);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    logger.error("Exception : ControllerFPC.calculateLoadVal en la lectura del fichero de propiedades  " + e.getMessage());
                    resultborrar="Exception : ControllerFPC.calculateLoadVal en la lectura del fichero de propiedades  " + e.getMessage();
                }


                return "exito"+resultborrar;
            }

}
```

What I've acctually get in my application:`

```
2019-03-29 10:54:16.506  INFO 26296 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3688eb5b: startup date [Fri Mar 29 10:54:16 CET 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-03-29 10:54:16.696  INFO 26296 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2019-03-29 10:54:16.727  INFO 26296 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7738e7d1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.6.RELEASE)

2019-03-29 10:54:21 INFO  ControllerFPC:516 - Starter of APP  
 Finnish starting process
```

As you can see my application doesn't go any further and I'm worried about that.

What I expect is something like:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)

2019-03-29 10:46:26.662  INFO 7124 --- [           main] com.demo.SpringBootWithKafkaApplication  : Starting SpringBootWithKafkaApplication on ESX5CD8051MG5 with PID 7124 (C:\Users\llacadena\git\spring-boot-kafka\target\classes started by llacadena in C:\Users\llacadena\git\spring-boot-kafka)
2019-03-29 10:46:26.664  INFO 7124 --- [           main] com.demo.SpringBootWithKafkaApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-03-29 10:46:26.692  INFO 7124 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@3d680b5a: startup date [Fri Mar 29 10:46:26 CET 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-03-29 10:46:27.191  INFO 7124 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b4a0ee3c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-03-29 10:46:27.441  INFO 7124 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9000 (http)
2019-03-29 10:46:27.453  INFO 7124 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-03-29 10:46:27.454  INFO 7124 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
2019-03-29 10:46:27.457  INFO 7124 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME\bin%;C:\opt\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Webex\Webex\Applications;C:\Users\llacadena\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\llacadena\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\llacadena\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\llacadena\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\llacadena\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin;C:\bin\zookeper\zookeeper-3.4.13\bin;;.]
2019-03-29 10:46:27.513  INFO 7124 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-03-29 10:46:27.513  INFO 7124 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 823 ms
2019-03-29 10:46:27.553  INFO 7124 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-03-29 10:46:27.555  INFO 7124 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-03-29 10:46:27.556  INFO 7124 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-03-29 10:46:27.556  INFO 7124 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-03-29 10:46:27.556  INFO 7124 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-03-29 10:46:27.668  INFO 7124 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-03-29 10:46:27.774  INFO 7124 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@3d680b5a: startup date [Fri Mar 29 10:46:26 CET 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-03-29 10:46:27.806  INFO 7124 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/kafka/publish],methods=[POST]}" onto public void com.demo.controllers.KafkaController.sendMessageToKafkaTopic(java.lang.String)
2019-03-29 10:46:27.808  INFO 7124 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2019-03-29 10:46:27.809  INFO 7124 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2019-03-29 10:46:27.824  INFO 7124 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-03-29 10:46:27.824  INFO 7124 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2019-03-29 10:46:27.955  INFO 7124 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2019-03-29 10:46:27.971  INFO 7124 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483547
2019-03-29 10:46:27.982  INFO 7124 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
2019-03-29 10:46:28.018  INFO 7124 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 1.0.2
2019-03-29 10:46:28.018  INFO 7124 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : 2a121f7b1d402825
2019-03-29 10:46:28.021  INFO 7124 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 
2019-03-29 10:46:28.041  INFO 7124 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9000 (http) with context path ''
2019-03-29 10:46:28.044  INFO 7124 --- [           main] com.demo.SpringBootWithKafkaApplication  : Started SpringBootWithKafkaApplication in 1.621 seconds (JVM running for 2.053)
```

------Update.-----

---

I've noticed that this started after I've the configuration of reading the applitcation.yml file from a remote config-server. So I looked in my bootstrap.properties file what is happening.

```
spring.application.name=kafkaclient

ribbon.eureka.enabled=false

 this is the default
spring.cloud.config.profile=dev
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://config-service-remote.domain.corp
```

If I comment the line where the config server(spring.cloud.config.uri) is declared and the profile (spring.cloud.config.profile) the application continues to deploy. But the problem is that I need to read from that config-server, so any ideas why is this happening?

### ----update 2 -----

As deadpool recomended I started a new project without the ControllerFPC class and created a new main class that only starts the application. I inspired myself in this source (https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-spring-boot-application) but still getting the same issue. When I declare the bootstrap variable (spring.cloud.config.uri=http://config-service-remote.domain.corp) my application doesn´t finish to deploy.

----- Solution ----

Well belive it or not the problem has nothing to do with the config server or whatever I said previously. My problem was my applications.yml, and the mistake was very silly but also very confusing because it makes no sense. The problem is that if you use the tabulator to keep the structure you will end up crashing the file so nothing will work, of course you won't understand and finnally you will be frustrated. So better that tabulate use the space bar, it sounds silly but worked for me. 
well I show you a nice example of what the problem was

`````````````````````````````````````
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      group-id: foo <-- my problem was here because I tabulate this line. 
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

app:
  topic:
    foo: foo.t

logging:
  level:
    root: WARN
    org.springframework.web: INFO
    com.memorynotfound: DEBUG

````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````

Comment: why everything in only `ControllerFPC`? why don't you separate each of them to config.service, main class etc..