# Spring boot AOP configuration in external Jar file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop

I am writing a new spring boot app that is using existing jar files that work fine in other non spring boot applications (they are using spring).

In our service layer, we are using spring transactions and spring AOP that have their configurations defined in an XML file. For example:

```xml
<!-- the transactional advice (i.e. what 'happens'; see the <aop:advisor/> bean below) -->
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
    <tx:attributes>
        <!-- all methods starting with 'find' are read-only -->
        <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        
        <!-- all methods starting with 'get' are read-only -->
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRED"/>

        <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>


<!-- ensure that the above transactional advice runs for any execution
     of an operation on any service -->
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="com.company.app.common.aspect.SystemArchitecture.serviceTransaction()"
                 advice-ref="dbTransaction" order="1010"  />

    <aop:aspect ref="verifyDatasourceSwitch" order="1001">
        <aop:around pointcut="com.company.app.common.aspect.SystemArchitecture.serviceOperation()"
                    method="verifyDatasource" />
    </aop:aspect>

    <aop:aspect ref="appDatasourceSwitch" order="12">
        <aop:around pointcut="com.company.app.common.aspect.SystemArchitecture.controlDatasource()"
                    method="switchToControl" />
    </aop:aspect>

    <aop:aspect ref="controlMongoDatabaseSwitch" order="13">
        <aop:around pointcut="com.company.app.common.aspect.SystemArchitecture.controlMongoDatabase()"
                    method="switchToControl" />
    </aop:aspect>   
</aop:config>
```

The aspects and pointcuts are defined like this:

```java
@Aspect
public class SystemArchitecture
{
    /**
     * A join point in the service layer if the method is defined
     * in a type in the com.company.app.service package or
     * any sub-package under that
     */
    @Pointcut("within(com.company.app.service..*)")
    public void inServiceLayer() {}

    @Pointcut("inServiceLayer() && this(com.company.app.service.Service)")
    public void serviceRegularOperation() {}
    /**
     * A service operation is the execution of any method defined on a service
     * interface.  This definition assumes that interfaces are placed in the
     * "service" package, and that implementations are in sub-packages.
     */
    @Pointcut("serviceRegularOperation() || serviceBrandOperation() || serviceCustomerOperation() || serviceWithChangeLoggingOperation() || serviceNonStandardService()")
    public void serviceOperation() {}
    
    @Pointcut("serviceOperation() && !@annotation(com.company.app.service.advice.NoTransaction)")
    public void serviceTransaction() {}
}
```

This is all working correctly in other apps that are using it.

In the spring boot app, I have a configuration class that includes the xml config containing the above.

```java
@Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:config/application.properties")
    @ImportResource({ "classpath:aspect.xml",
                      "classpath:rabbit.xml",
                     "classpath:email.xml",
                     "classpath:approval.xml",
                     "classpath:event.xml",
                     "classpath:facades.xml",
                     "classpath:general.xml",
                     "classpath:velocity.xml",
                     "classpath:mongo.xml",
                     "classpath:services.xml",
                     "classpath:velocity-service.xml",
                     "classpath:velocity-facade.xml",
                     "classpath:sharedservices.xml",
                     "classpath:jobs.xml",
                     "classpath:cachesharedfacades.xml",
                     "classpath:sharedContext-security.xml",
                     "classpath:hibernate-common-session-factory.xml",
                     "classpath:hibernate-datasource.xml",
                     "classpath:hibernate-local-transaction-manager.xml",
                     "classpath:hibernate-mysql-session-factory.xml",
                     "classpath:hibernate-repositories.xml",
                     "classpath:mysql-repositories.xml",
                     "classpath:hibernate-template.xml",
                     "classpath:repository-mbeans.xml",
                     "classpath:spring-transaction.xml" })
    public class ApplicationConfiguration 
    {
    }
```

The main application is created as:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class GraphqlApplication 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run( GraphqlApplication.class, args );
    }
}
```

When the application is started up, I see warnings such as:

```
Bean 'adminTypeService' of type [com.company.app.service.impl.AdminTypeServiceImpl]
  is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors
  (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

Which I assume is causing the proxying not to happen, which is probably what is stopping the AOP calls from working.

Am I missing something?  I can see the beans defined in the services.xml are created, but when calling a service methods, they interface isn't proxied, so there are no transactions or other supporting functions called via AOP that need to happen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please go through the SO [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201726/tracking-down-cause-of-springs-not-eligible-for-auto-proxying) . Also `AdminTypeServiceImpl` , I assume is not final