# Spring not creating Proxy Object for A Spring Service that has a public method with @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have a RestController that has a Service with a public method annotated with `@Transactional`. The RestController class is annotated with `@RestController`, and the service bean is injected using Constructor injection. You can assume that the service is written as a different public class. `MyRespository` is annotated with `@Repository` annotation.

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyController {

    private final MyService myService;

    @PatchMapping("/some-endpoint")
    public SomeCustomObject updateSomeObject(){
        // This prints `package.x.y.z.MyService` as opposed to something like `package.x.y.z.MyService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a1b2c3d4`
        log.info("myService proxy {}", myService.getClass());
        return myService.updateSomeObject();
    }

}


@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyService extends SomeBaseService{

    private final MyRepository myRepository;

    @Transactional(rollbackOn = SomeCustomException.class)
    public SomeCustomObject updateSomeObject(){
        log.info("Is Transaction Active {} Name {} ", TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive(),
                TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName()); // This prints `false` and `null`
        SomeCustomObject someCustomObject = getTheObj();
        updateTheObject(someCustomObject);
    } // Updates are not persisted to the database.

    private SomeCustomObject getTheObj(){
        return myRepository.HugeMethodNameThatsWhyUsedAMethodAsWrapper();
    }

    private void updateTheObject(SomeCustomObject someCustomObject){
        myRepository.setSomething(someCustomObject);
    }
}
```

On googling, I found Spring may not be able to create a proxy if circular dependencies are there. So I tried Field injection using `@Autowired` still the log output show the real object.

In one of the other controllers which have another service, which also extends from the `SomeBaseService` like `MyService` class, injected, the proxy is being created and all these classes are within the same base package.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201726/tracking-down-cause-of-springs-not-eligible-for-auto-proxying

Comment: `javax.transaction.Transactional` - that is wrong annotation, should be `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`

Comment: Did you add `@EnableTransactionManagement` to your `@SpringBootApplication` class? Also, `TransactionSynchronizationManager` class belongs to `...reactive` package, so maybe you will need to define `ReactiveTransactionManager` bean, e.g. `org.springframework.data.mongodb.ReactiveMongoTransactionManager`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Nope, it is not. It works as expected.

Comment: @geobreze Yes. `@EnableTransactionManagement` is added.

Answer (score 1):

The first comment mentioning a possible duplicate helped me move forward. I changed the Constructor injection to field injection and added `@Lazy` and it started working.
More Information can be found here:

- [Spring not creating Proxy Object for A Spring Service that has a public method with @Transactional annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76374340/spring-not-creating-proxy-object-for-a-spring-service-that-has-a-public-method-w?noredirect=1#comment134675117_76374340)
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-not-eligible-for-auto-proxying
- https://synyx.de/blog/bean-x-of-type-y-is-not-eligible-for-getting-processed-by-all-beanpostprocessors/
- https://www.startups.com/community/questions/7706/springboot-doesn-t-load-bean-globalmethodsecurityconfiguration-err-not-eligible